# Send mail with output of a Filter Array data in Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to send the output of a Filter Array in an e-mail body or as attachment?

I'm testing some error handling and want to send the error that occurred in a previous scope in my Logic App.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using and Action: "Parse JSON" with the output Body from the Filter array and then using the values I was interested of when sending an e-mail.

Comment: screenshots and code would be great. please add them